# Get the name of the column of a largest number in an Excel array?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a data set with numeric values, from which I need to get the name of the column in which is located the largest number, row by row. Please see below (I'm omitting the columns names for confidentiality):

[image: Numeric data set]

Any thoughts?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you trying to get the information to?

Comment: I tried =COLUMN(MAX(range,range)) thinking that I would later apply conditional format and Paint the cell with column value accordingly to its number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column Names are in row 1 and your data is A:S, put this in row 2 of your column:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A2:S2)/(A2:S2=MAX(A2:S2)),1))
```

It will return the column number to the INDEX which then will return the name in row 1.

Comment: It works, thanks so much! Just to understand, what are the values "15" and "6" for??